# Webmethods IS: Can Webmethods IS call multiple request from XML parameter/attribute from 1 response message

Tags: xml, webmethods

I am new in SAG Webmethod.

I have one scenario where I want that SAG Webmethods IS call one web service. The request returns back XML response. In the xml response, there is one parameter/attribute which I want to use to make call to another webservice.

My question here is, the first web service call is stateless ( closing the connection as soon as I am getting the response). Now, I am reading the xml response and if the respective attribute is found, then I am asking Webmethod to call another stateless Webservice.

Is this scenario available in webmethods and can this be achieved.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, This can be absolutely achieved in wM.

1. Make a call to first webservice
2. store the result in cache or simply map the result in document
3. add Branch step and check desired parameter/attribute value
4. if found then make the call to another webservice
   P.S. Please make sure you add try catch block with proper retry conditions to handle the intermediate errors from webservics and to maintain the session if you want.

Comment: thanks. But I want to call the second service as independent of first. Which will ensure that if the second webservice is failed (due to network error) then we dont have to start from step1 rather, only second webservice call can be made again. Any thoughts?

Comment: Ok! from 4th step you can make call to second webservice with that second webservice connector and and add retry logic in catch block. You already have the stored results of first webservice so you can make second call independent of first call. Let me know if it doesn't work.